# Javascript: naming option.dataset problem

Tags: javascript

I'm adding new lines with a `<select>` and an `<input>`. The `<input>` is updated if the `<option>`-dataset has a value.

Here's some of the code:

```
var optionsArray = [
    { value: "", text: "Pick" },
    { value: "1", text: "Option 1", dataUnitprice: "100" },
    { value: "2", text: "Option 2", dataUnitprice: "200" },
    { value: "3", text: "Option 3", dataUnitprice: "" },
];
```

```
    optionsArray.forEach(function (optionData) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = optionData.value;
        option.textContent = optionData.text;
        option.dataset.dataEnhedspris = optionData.dataUnitprice;
        selectClone.appendChild(option);
    });
```

All good, but it doesnt work and in the console, I get this:
`<option value="1" data-data-unitprice="">Option 1</option>`

My question: Why suddenly "data-data-unitprice" ? It's not in my code, and it should be "dataUnitprice"

Hope someone with better js-skills than me can help :-)

Maybe I need to have a "-" in my code..?

Here's the SelectClone:

```
var selectClone = document.createElement("select");
selectClone.className = "select-option form-control form-control-sm";
selectClone.setAttribute("data-show-content", "true");
selectClone.name = "kategori";
selectClone.required = true;
selectClone.onchange = function () {
    updateUnitprice(this);
};
```

Comment: How is `selectClone` defined? Please add the relevant HTML code for more context.

Comment: This is how data attributes work, they start with "data-"
Learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes
Or you can use `option.setAttribute("dataUnitprice", "200")`

Comment: CamelCase is used in the JS and it translates into kebab-case, so `dataset.enhedsPris` becomes `data-enheds-pris`

Comment: Thats it - give me 10 minutes :-)

Comment: Hmm, still doenst work.
Here's from the console:
<option value="1" data-dataenhedspris="460">Option 1</option>

Comment: WOW - "option.setAttribute("dataUnitprice", "200")" did the trick. THANKS !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are making things more complicated for yourself. Why not drop the extra data-* attribute and use the value attribute instead? That will make it easier to the the value in the `updateUnitprice()` function.

```js
var optionsArray = [{
    value: "",
    text: "Pick"
  },
  {
    value: "100",
    text: "Option 1"
  },
  {
    value: "200",
    text: "Option 2"
  },
  {
    value: "",
    text: "Option 3"
  }
];

var selectClone = document.createElement("select");
selectClone.className = "select-option form-control form-control-sm";
selectClone.setAttribute("data-show-content", "true");
selectClone.name = "kategori";
selectClone.required = true;
selectClone.addEventListener('change', updateUnitprice);
document.forms.form01.appendChild(selectClone);


optionsArray.forEach(function(optionData) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = optionData.value;
  option.textContent = optionData.text;
  selectClone.appendChild(option);
});

function updateUnitprice(e){
  console.log('You selected', e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<form name="form01"></form>
```

Comment: I did exactly that - and it work like a charm:
option.setAttribute("dataUnitprice", "200")"